# How to convert an array of HTML colours into into a picture?

Tags: gimp, html, pixel, hex, javascript

I have an array of colors, for example:

```
    A=[['#ff00ff', '#00ff00', '#ffff00', '#00ff00', '#0000ff', '#00ffff', '#00ffff'],
       ['#0000ff', '#0000ff', '#00ffff', '#00ff00', '#ffff00', '#00ff00', '#00ff00'],
       ['#ffff00', '#0000ff', '#0000ff', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00'],
       ['#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#00ff00', '#00ff00', '#00ff00'],
       ['#00ff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#00ff00', '#00ff00', '#00ff00', '#00ff00'],
       ['#00ff00', '#00ff00', '#00ff00', '#00ff00', '#00ff00', '#0000ff', '#0000ff'],
       ['#0000ff', '#00ff00', '#00ff00', '#00ff00', '#0000ff', '#0000ff', '#0000ff']]
```

I want to convert this into a picture such that the pixel of coordinate `(i,j)` has the color `A[i][j]`.

**Question:** How do I do that in Gimp (or directly in HTML, or anything more relevant)?

*Remark:* The real array I want to convert is 5000 by 5000 (i.e. 25000000 pixels) so I can’t do this by hand and I need an automatic procedure.

---

The following picture is a compression of the result:

[image]

About what does this mean, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/199543/34538).

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work about it? What's the end goal? This question needs to be more specific than it currently is IMO

Comment: @ZachSaucier: see the last picture [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/199543/34538)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a few lines in Python:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy

A = […]

convert = lambda string: [int(string[i:i+2],base=16) for i in (1,3,5)]
B = numpy.array([map(convert,line) for line in A], dtype=numpy.uint8)
image = Image.fromarray(B, mode="RGB")
image.save("image.png")
```

A short explanation:

- `convert` is a function that converst an HTML colour string (like `'#00ff00'`) to a list of colour values (e.g., `[0,256,0]`).
- `B` is an array where each pixel is converted with `convert`.
- `Image.fromarray` is for converting precisely such arrays into images.

Comment: Python language is interesting for my use, because I compute the array with [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) (mode Cython). Do you know how computing this image directly with Sage?

Comment: I do not know about the Cython mode of Sage, but in regular Sage the above code works, if I remove `Image` from the first line and add `from PIL import Image`.

Comment: This works, but the image is not what I expected. In fact I want an image like [that here](http://jsfiddle.net/wu5s685u/1/). Do you know how doing that with Sage?

Comment: Apparently, PIL needs Numpy arrays to be of a specific datatype. I hopefully fixed that now (see edit).

Comment: Yes, this is exaclty that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily using the `<canvas>` element and some JavaScript... `A` is already in JS format!

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"), // Select our canvas element
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"), // Save the context we're going to use
    width = A[0].length, // Get the width of the array
    height = A.length, // Get the height of the array
    scale = 10; // Scales the whole image by this amount, set to 1 for default size

// Make sure the canvas is no larger than the size we need
canvas.width = width * scale; 
canvas.height = height * scale; 

// Loop through each color and draw that section
for(var row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for(var col = 0; col < width; col++) { // Since there are nested arrays we need two for loops
        ctx.fillStyle = A[row][col]; // Set the color to the one specified
        ctx.fillRect(col * scale, row * scale, scale, scale); // Actually draw the rectangle
    }
}
```

**Note**: This solution colors the pixels in a left to right then top to bottom way because that's how I interpreted the format of your array. If you need it to go top to bottom and then left to right, just switch `row` and `col` in the `fillRect` line [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/wu5s685u/2/):

```
ctx.fillRect(col * scale, row * scale, scale, scale);
```

Check out the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wu5s685u/1/)!

Comment: My 1000x1000 array is quite big for a "copy-paste".  How can I transport it?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux Copy paste should be able to handle it... But you could open it up in a text editor, change the format to match the one I have here, then Save As a .js file (or .html if you format it that way)

Comment: In fact, I would like something like: `var A = read(/home/palcoux/array.txt);` Do you know the good code for that?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux I do, but that's a separate question than the one asked here :)